# Frequency between dates

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I have a query that returns Name in one column and Date in another. One name will have multiple rows, each containing a different date.

Is it possible to calculate the average number of days between each date, grouped for each person, so that I end up with one column listing each person once, and then another column with the average?

Thanks

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Sample data and desired results would also help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The average timing between the dates -- assuming they are in order -- is the maximum minus the minimum divided by one less than the count.

Date functions vary significantly be database, but the idea is:

```
select name,
       (max(date) - min(date)) / nullif(count(*) - 1, 0)
from t
group by name;
```

Not all database support the difference of dates.  But all do have some way of measuring the number of days between two dates.  So your syntax might differ, although the idea is the same.

In SQL Server this would be:

```
select name,
       datediff(day, min(date), max(date)) * 1.0 / nullif(count(*) - 1, 0)
from t
group by name;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon! I modified it a little to  datediff(dd,min(G1.POST_DATE),max(G1.POST_DATE)) / nullif(count(*) - 1, 0)
and that seems to be working. Is it possible to show 2 decimal places?

Comment: Thanks again, now it says that 'date' is not a recognized datediff option. Any ideas?